# How to create share folder between Host and Docker container via docker API

Tags: python, docker

How can I create a share folder between Host and Docker container via docker API?

I am able to do it via CLI:

```
docker run -v folder on host:folder on container -d --privileged image name".
```

How can I achieve the same thing with the help of Docker API? I am using Docker Python SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link might help you in creating / sharing volume using docker api. An example using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{ "Binds": ["/home/user/folder/:/opt/folder:rw"] }' \
    http://127.0.0.1:{port}/containers/[id]/start
```

For detailed info, see [Docker API docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/ContainerCreate).

For docker python SDK

```
container_id = cli.create_container(
    'busybox', 'ls', volumes=['/mnt/vol1', '/mnt/vol2'],
    host_config=cli.create_host_config(binds={
        '/home/user1/': {
            'bind': '/mnt/vol2',
            'mode': 'rw',
        },
        '/var/www': {
            'bind': '/mnt/vol1',
            'mode': 'ro',
        }
    })
)
```

See create containers section in below link

http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Comment: So I am using the below API to run  the Docker:client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run("ct_bridge",auto_remove=True,privileged=True,detach=True)... Here How can I do that??

Comment: If it works then can accept the answer, it might be useful for others who are looking for solution